# Basic C++ program cannot be closed even by ending processes

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction

Whenever I compile a basic program, even a simple 'Hello, world!', the program becomes unresponsive when trying to close. I can't even end the process with task manager. The only solution to close the program is to restart my computer.

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit and I've used Visual C++, Gygwin GCC and GNU GCC with CodeBlocks and Eclipse.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "Hello, world!";
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: When you say you've tried multiple compilers, do you mean you've tried multiple different IDE's?

Comment: I guess trying multiple compilers means that the problem really is in your code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Or with the Windows console service

Comment: Well, I've never written a Visual C++ console program myself, but the first thing I'd try is tacking a newline onto the end of that string.

Comment: The above code compiles and runs fine in VS2013, which leaves me to believe Captain Obvlious is leaning in the correct direction. (Of course, VS wasn't explicitly stated as being used)

Comment: What IDE/Compiler/Operating System are you using?

Comment: I found you a compiler that works right: http://ideone.com/CPHrd9

Comment: [I don't see the problem.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e237788c72b86b35)

Comment: @Inisheer I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate x64; I've used GNU GCC and Cygwin GCC through both CodeBlocks, Eclipse and command prompt. I've also used Visual Studio and have had the same problem.

Comment: @remyabel I've tried multiple IDE's and multiple compilers. I don't really think it's my code; it's pretty standard from what I understand. I can make console applications in C# without it doing this too.

Comment: 'The only solution to close the program is to restart my computer' - you installed or updated any drivers recently?

Comment: Shouldn't `using namespace std;` be before `int main()`?

Answer (score 5):

When I was taking c++ classes that used MS Visual Studio 2010 our first hello world app was

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << "Hello World";
  return 0;
}
```

If you have compiled a debug version and have set a break point at the return so you could see your apps output, then you will not be able to exit the application by clicking the little x on the console window. If you click the little x, try to exit using alt + f4, or try to kill the process using taskmgr it will look like it freezed. In order to work around this you need to go to whatever debugger you are using and stop debugging or continue past the break point.  In Visual Studio it is the little red square in toolbar or you can press f5 to continue.

Comment: oh hell, let's have an upvote for helpful explanation of break points. this is not completely unthinkable :)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is it. I've ran the release version and have had the same problem.

Comment: It's not necessarily due to a breakpoint, I think the problem just occcurs when using the debugger in general. YOu have to go to 'stop debugging' rather than click exit on the console window.